# Issues with Site and Global Assets After Optimizely Upgrade

Tags: episerver, optimizely

I am currently working on upgrading our system from Optimizely 11 to Optimizely 12. I have successfully resolved compile-time errors, and the application is running, but I am encountering an issue related to the loading of site and global assets.

Previously, our Optimizely 11 site was accessible at ***loca.dummy.com***. After the upgrade to Optimizely 12, the site is now available at ***loca.dummy.com:7047***. While I can load the site without any problems, the site assets and global assets media items do not load.

What's perplexing is that there are no apparent errors, and when I navigate to the media assets URL, it appears blank. I'm wondering if there are specific settings related to site and global assets that need to be configured post-upgrade to ensure the proper loading of media items.

I have crossed checked the Manage website section in admin mode for the particular site & **Use Site Assets** option for the site is checked.

Any input or feedback is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Can you upload images to "Media" and have them display properly? If so, do the new blobs appear alongside existing ones? In other words, is blob storage correctly configured?

Comment: Yes. I can upload Media contents & access the newly added ones. This is however not the case with the existing media items .When trying to open the existing ones,the page is blank .The only difference i see is in terms of Url change wherein the upgrade url has port number with it.  For Blob storage: we do have a seperate db to store the media items apart from Episerver database. So after upgrade can we not use the same blob storage db or is it required to use the new blob storage db as well?

Comment: Sounds like existing ones haven't been migrated to the new blob storage?

Comment: @TedNyberg Maybe a  silly question but can i not use the existing blob storage that is used for 11 ?

Comment: Sure, but you have to check your blob storage config - it seems your migrated/old blobs aren't in the new blob storage. That's why they can't be loaded.

Comment: Thank you @TedNyberg. The new blob storage is empty & so its not loading any assets. I have raised a ticket to Optimizely for the new connection string to the blob storage since that is handled by them for us. Thanks once again for clarifying.